# AWS route53 doesnt resolve any records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have such problem - Route53 does not resolve any added ( A,CNAME, ALIAS ) records to world, but resolve if i execute it with aws NS server

> nslookup x.site.com ns-1583.awsdns-57.org
> Server:        ns-1583.awsdns-57.org
> Address:   205.251.197.203#53
>
> Name:  x.site.com
> Address: address

What it could be ?

Comment: Did you accidentally create a "private hosted zone" instead of a "public hosted zone"?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your domain registrar is configured to use Amazon DNS servers?

Visit http://whois.domaintools.com/site.com to confirm.

Replace the site.com above with your actual domain. Then check to make sure the assigned name servers on the domain point to the name servers assigned to your domain at Route 53.

Comment: Hello Rodrigo - *site.com and x.site.com it is only example - and yes it is registered domain.

Comment: Yes I understand those are example domains, my answer suggested you confirm your domain at that url, replacing the example with your domain, and confirming the assigned name servers.  Looks like that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in different NS-serervers on domain registrator and route53.
Thanks for help.
Closed

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.